# Lumia 520 overheat and sudden battery drain

Tags: lumia-520

My lumia 520 suddenly started overheating and the battery doesnt charges atleast to even 10%.I couln't even use it for few minutes on charging(gets heated xtremrly while at charge).Couldn't even take contact backup.But contacts are very important for me.Can anyone state about the problem

Comment: Try Replacing the battery.

Comment: But it is normal till this problem had occured.How can this happen suddenly ? What may be the problem?

Comment: Turn on flight mode and check whether still experiencing the issue. I had the same problem which was with phone antenna.

Comment: It is 8.0 not 8.1....

Comment: Then I'd recommend contacting service and get them to replace your phone. Did you check if your contacts have been synched to Outlook.com?

Comment: My contacts are not properly synched,that is the main problem.